# How can I convert this Bash prompt to zsh?

Tags: terminal, bash, zsh

I have the following configuration for Bash:

```
#   Change Prompt
#   ------------------------------------------------------------
    export PS1="________________________________________________________________________________\n| \e[0;34m\u\e[m@\e[0;32m\h\e[m {\e[0;33m\w\e[m} --- \e[0;35m\D{%F %T}\e[m \n| $: "
    export PS2="|  $: "
```

I tried replacing the `\` with `%`, but it didn't work. What can I do to make this work in zsh?

Essentially this ends up looking like the following (minus colors):

```
________________________________________________________________________________
| user1@MacBook-Pro {~} --- 2020-09-14 13:17:39
| $:
```

Comment: Did you look at the zsh man page? Are you struggling with the prompt in general or mainly with the encoding of escape sequences?

Comment: mainly with the escapes, I think, I can't figure out how to customize the colors

Comment: Unfortunately I don’t know the answer, but if you don’t find it here, the Zsh Users’ list is full of super-helpful folks. I’ve been on it since the 90s! You can find out more here too: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Arc/mlist.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As others have already mentioned, there are built-in sequences for setting colours, like `%F{red}`. If you want to include more exotic terminal control codes, you can do it like this:

```
PS1=$'%{\e[1m%}%m%{\e[0m%}'
```

(This should make the prompt display your hostname in boldface, on most typical terminals.) There are two things to notice here

1. Using the `$'`... `'` quoting mechanism to include control characters in the string. This is described under QUOTING in the `zshmisc(1)` man page. (In other words, this is what makes `\e` work).
2. Using `%{`...`%}` to indicate that the enclosed sequence does not cause the cursor to move.
3. (`%m` expands to the host name. This is described under PROMPT SEQUENCES in `zshmisc(1)`, but you probably knew this already.)

(Alright then, three things. Monty Python fans will know what reference I would put here, others won't care. :-) )

Answer (score 2):

From https://scriptingosx.com/2019/07/moving-to-zsh-06-customizing-the-zsh-prompt/

> Adding a bit of color or shades of gray to the prompt can make it more
> readable. In bash you need cryptic escape codes to switch the colors.
> zsh provides an easier way. To turn the directory in the path blue,
> you can use:
>
> ```
> PROMPT='%F{blue}%1~%f %# '
> ```
>
> The F stands for ‘Foreground color.’ zsh understands the colors black,
> red, green, yellow, blue, magenta, cyan and white. %F or %f resets to
> the default text color.

There are more details about this on the linked page (and in `man zsh`).